# React js: Converting Material-UI functional code into class component throws typerror

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, material-ui, material-design

So i am using material ui login page code which is a functional component, so as per my requirement i need to convert it into class component.
**but converting it into class component throws error: "Cannot assign to read only property 'classes' of object '#'"**

I have globally passed MiuiThemeProvider down into DOM tree in index.js file by wrapping app.js file inside it.
I have carefully removed all hooks like replacing makeStyles with withStyles.

Now in code sandbox link shared below you can see my class component, which is showing error(Type Error: Cannot assign to read only property 'classes' of object '#')

**The original material-UI functional component code is running fine but when converted to class component throws the mentioned error**

**codeSandbox link with all files and dependencies**: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-goodall-rzdg9?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `withStyles` two times.
`withStyles`  it is HOC, please check [Doc](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#higher-order-component-api)

You need to remove `withStyles` from useStyles
[image]